# Prove if A is an $ n \times n$ real matrix with $\vert \left(A-I\right)_{i,j}\vert < \epsilon$ for $ 1 \le i,j \le n$, then A is invertible

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there exists an $\epsilon > 0 $ with the property that if A is an $ n \times n$ real matrix with $\vert \left(A-I\right)_{i,j}\vert < \epsilon$ for $ 1 \le i,j \le n$, then A is invertible (here $B_{i,j}$ denotes the $(i,j)$ entry of B).

I am guessing the matrix A is very close to I and assume it is invertible because $det(I) = 1$ But I don't know how to prove it. Could you please help me to solve it? Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1):

an alternate way is by considering the matrix norm $$\|M\| = \max_{\|x\|=1} \|Mx\|$$

lemma : if $A$ is invertible and $\|B\| < \frac1{\|A^{-1}\|}$ then $A+B$ is invertible.

proof : $\min_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| = \frac1{\|A^{-1}\|}$ hence $\min_{\|x\| = 1} \|(A+B)x\| \ge  \left(\min_{\|x\| = 1}\|Ax\| \right)  -\left(\max_{\|x\| = 1}\|Bx\| \right) = \frac1{\|A^{-1}\|} - \|B\| > 0$ hence for every $x \ne 0$ : $(A+B)x \ne 0$ hence $A+B$ is invertible.